# storing an array of nodes in linked list

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, nodes

I have a problem with storing an array of nodes in linked list, each node contains a fixed size array of values. My program can compile without errors, but there is no output, and I do not know why. Here is my struct function for Node and list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 20

typedef struct NODE Node;
struct NODE
{
char *bucket[SIZE]; 
int count;       
Node *next;
};

  Node *new_node()
{
   Node *curr=malloc(sizeof( Node ));
   curr->count=0;
   curr->next=NULL;
   return curr;
}

void add_node(Node *node,char *x)
{

    node->bucket[node->count] = (char *)malloc( strlen( x ) + 1 );
    strcpy(node->bucket[node->count],x);
    node->count++;
}
typedef struct LIST List;

struct LIST 
{
    Node *top;
};

List *construct() 
{
List *list;

list = malloc( sizeof( List ) );
list->top = NULL;

return list;
}
void insert( List *list, char *new_string )
{
 Node *newNode = new_node();
 Node *curr;

 curr = list->top;
if ( NULL == curr)
{
  curr=newNode;
}
add_node(newNode,new_string);

 }


void print( List *list )
{
  Node *curr = list->top;

  while ( NULL != curr ) 
  {
   for(int i=0;i<curr->count;i++)
   {
    printf( "%s\n", curr->bucket[i]);
   }
    curr = curr->next;
  }
}
```

Here is my test function:

```
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
 {

   List *list=construct();
   char *ch="a";

   insert(list,ch);
   insert(list,ch);
   insert(list,ch);
   insert(list,ch);
   insert(list,ch);
   print(list);


   return 0;
  }
```

Any ideas why this is not behaving as expected?

Comment: Your insert method loses the newNode you make. I am pretty sure if you check the list->curr in the print it will be a null.

Comment: Thanks for your advice :)The newNode is null,but I am not really understand why I loses newNode?

Comment: Number of details cause this. First of all you never update your list->top, secondly you are sending a copy of list to insert, a copy of newnode to add. Your add method also seems very dubios as you are allocating a sizeof(strlen) on a char point in the char array. Have a look at http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-call-by-value-or-call-by-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue is your `insert()` function.

```
void insert(List *list, char *new_string)
{
        Node *newNode = new_node();
        Node *curr;

        curr = list->top;
        if (NULL == curr) {
                /* OK. We set curr to newNode, but what happens to curr? */
                curr = newNode; 
        }
        /* String is added to newNode, but what happens to newNode? */
        add_node(newNode, new_string);
}
```

If you instead say (which you might intended):

```
if (list->top == NULL) {
    list->top = newNode;
}
```

you would keep *first* `newNode`, but loose the rest.

---

When it comes to `add_node()` there is nothing directly wrong with it. Biggest issue is that you do not check if `node->count` is 20. Secondly it has a ***very bad name***. Take care when you name functions else your code becomes very hard to read and maintain.

`add_node` does ***not*** add a node. The name should reflect what it does.

For example you could say:
`insert` should be named `add_node`, and `add_node` should be named something like `add_string`, `push_string`, `bucket_fill` or the like. At least that would be somewhat better.

It is also redundant to cast *malloc*:

```
node->bucket[node->count] = (char*)malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
```

Better (IMHO):

```
node->bucket[node->count] = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
```

---

There is various ways to add a new node. One way is to loop until last and add:

```
    while (node->next != NULL) {
            node = node->next;
    }
    node->next = new_node();
    bucket_fill(node->next, str);
```

If you have a separate struct for list, you can keep track of head and tail:

```
struct list {
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
};
```

And then something like:

```
void node_add(struct list *list, char *str)
{
        struct node *new_node = node_create();

        bucket_fill(new_node, str);

        if (list->head != NULL) {
                list->tail->next = new_node;
                list->tail = new_node;
        } else {
                list->head = new_node;
                list->tail = new_node;
        }
}
```

And so on and so forth.

---

Have a look at each step and try to keep track of the nodes.

Often one would not have a `struct list` and a `struct node`, but use `node` for both. A list is in essence the first node in a chain of nodes.

---

One thing that is really helpful when coding linked lists, and C in general, is to use Valgrind, (at least on Linux and the like). For this to be more useful you will first need to add `free_list()` functions to free up memory.

Make it a rule to always write a `free` function when you write a function using `malloc`.

Then run your program with:

```
$ valgrind ./my_program
```

If you use `gcc` compile with `-ggdb` to get line-numbers on the output from Valgrind.

The two cases that would be useful for you then is to ensure all memory are freed on exit. This makes sure you do not miss anything in your code. Secondly you will get warnings when you access uninitialized variables etc.

---

As a starter there is two things to look at:

1.) No leaks. *"in use at exit"* should be 0.

```
==13476== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13476==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13476==   total heap usage: 43 allocs, 43 frees, 424 bytes allocated
==13476== 
==13476== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

2.) Use of uninitialized values:

```
==12972== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12972==    by 0x8048838: insert (foo.c:120)
==12972==    by 0x804890E: main (foo.c:151)
                                      |
                                      |
                                      +--- Shows file and line-number.
```

Or:

```
==12820== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
...
```

And the like.

---

A typical *free* function could be something like:

```
void free_bucket(struct node *node)
{
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < node->count; ++i) {
                free(node->bucket[i]);
        }
}

void free_list(struct node *head)
{
        struct node *tmp_node;

        while (head != NULL) {
                free_bucket(head);
                tmp_node = head;
                head = head->next;
                free(tmp_node);
        }
}
```

Comment: @vera: Np :), There is a lot of ways to solve linked lists, and which way usually depends on various factors on what to use it for. Google *linked list example* etc. and read over some of the code. It can help further. Most important thing: *Keep it simple* until you have tested it well, then expand with new code. Get the basic functionality in first. Do not work on adding data such as *bucket* until it works well and you understand what is going on.